# Angular: Custom FormControl doesn't update view after FormGroup.reset()

Tags: angular

**This is my 'registration' page:**

- registration.component.html

  ```
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div formGroupName="locationGroup"
         class="location-group">

      <acme-location-picker formControlName="country"
                          [label]="'Country'"
                          [locations]="countries"></acme-location-picker>

      <acme-location-picker formControlName="city"
                          [label]="'City'"
                          [locations]="cities"></acme-location-picker>

  </div>
  ```
- registration.component.ts
      this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({

  ```
      firstName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],

      locationGroup: this.fb.group({
          country: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
          city: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      }),

  });

  public onRegistrationFormSubmit(): void {
      this.registrationForm.reset({ onlySelf: false });
  }

  public showValues(): void {
      console.log('values: ', this.registrationForm.value);
  }
  ```

**My custom 'location picker'**

- location-picker.component.html

  ```
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select [disabled]="disabled"
        (selectionChange)="onChange($event.value)">
          <mat-option [value]="null">...</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locations"
              [value]="location.code">
              {{location.name}} ({{location.code}})
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  ```
- location-picker.component.ts

  ```
  @Component({
      ...
      providers: [{
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => LocationPickerComponent),
          multi: true }]
  })
  export class LocationPickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
      @Input() public label: string;
      @Input() public locations: string[];

      selectedOption: string;
      disabled: boolean;
      onChange = (val: any) => { };
      onTouched = () => { };

      writeValue(val: string): void {
          console.log('writeValue:', val);
          this.selectedOption = val ? val : null;
      }
      setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
          this.disabled = isDisabled;
      }          
      registerOnChange(fn: () => void): void {
          this.onChange = fn;
      }
      registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
          this.onTouched = fn;
      }
  }
  ```

The onRegistrationFormSubmit() method effectively resets the whole form.

After I check the form's model with showValues(), I can see that all the fields of locationGroup are null.

HOWEVER, the UI of my custom location-picker doesn't update (doesn't show the three dots) despite of the fact, that the writeValue method is called.

All the other fields of the form are reset back to their respective values, except my custom formControl fields (countries and cities mat-select).

Here's a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-formcontrol-update?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Question is old but did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `value` property in `mat-select`.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [disabled]="disabled"
      [(value)]="selectedOption"
      (selectionChange)="onChange($event.value)">
        <mat-option [value]="null">...</mat-option>
        <mat-option
        *ngFor="let location of locations"
        [value]="location.code">
        {{location.name}} ({{location.code}})
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-formcontrol-update-demms9?file=src/app/location-picker/location-picker.component.html

Comment: I already considered this. I googled a bit and I found a couple of sources that didn't consider the two-way binding a good practice in this case...and what's even worse - this way it doesn't show validation errors. The writeWalue method should be utilized, I just don't know how...